How does gravity work if there are no other objects?
Let's say we're in deep space, there's nothing around - no planets, nothing. Now, if we put an 8in by 8in solid steel ball in this so called "space", would the steel ball have a gravitational field around it, no matter how small it would be?

Why wouldn't there be? The ball has mass, doesn't it?

What exactly do you mean by "how does gravity work"? There is more than one working theory of gravity.

@VincentThacker I feel like that might be out of the scope of this question...

forca single object perhaps not.... see Machs principle

Related question: How and in what way do force fields work and exist?

@R.Rankin see also my other comment

"no matter how small" What do you mean? The range of gravity is infinite.

FWIW, if you made a scale model of the Solar System in deep space, scaling all the distances and velocities, retaining the densities of the true Solar System bodies, then all of the orbital periods would be unchanged.

Yes, it would. And for a ball of those dimensions Newton's law of universal gravitation would predict exactly what that field would be.

for a single object in the universe, Machs principle comes into play.  essentially it claims the mass/inertia of an object is due the the distribution of all other objects. helped inspire einsteins theory. if it holds then no, there is no mass. or at least not the way were used to

@R.Rankin Mach's principle is functionally bunk. I've been told about it a lot of times and tried to read about it, but I've never been given an actual concrete representation of any "principle". As it turns out a Universe with a single particle/single object is perfectly well-defined according to all our current physical theories.

Mach’s principle is philosophically appealing, but insofar as we have been able to test it, it appears that the universe isn’t Machian

@controlgroup I realize the question is closed; just want to mention that, at the very least, the gravitational potential energy between some test object and every other object/mass energy in the universe certainly contributes to the test objects mass/energy. moreover in the standard model of particle physics we accept an all pervading higgs field in the universe which imbues mass. philosophically not very different IMHO

@R.Rankin The speed of light squared is a big number; GPE doesn’t add much mass in the grand scheme of things. And a big misconception: the Higgs mechanism primarily adds mass to the W and Z bosons - strangely-massive bosons carrying the weak force which as you know is a rare occurrence, hence “weak” - not all particles. And the Higgs field is, of course, independent of the existence of other matter, so it’s actually quite different from Mach’s idea.

@controlgroup. yeah, i get that most of the mass of matter is a result of strong binding within hadrons, in that sense leptons really are the only fermionic particles that we observe following a purely higgs based mass. to be completely honest my natural bias runs more in the direction of a wheelerian type geometrodynamics. but i see the appeal in an emergent origin for mass

@controlgroup just one more thought. a single and solitary fermionic particle in the universe would in fact have no mass, as there would be no higgs, gluons or otherwise.

Well, of course, if you drop all the quantum fields relating to mass there wouldn't be any mass. Mach's principle has nothing to do with it; a Universe containing the things necessary for a property to make sense i.e. the relevant quantum fields and a single particle would be a Universe with a single particle with those properties. That doesn't relate to "inertia over here being determined by mass out there", which is a common "formulation" of Mach's principle.

@controlgroup  Agreed, I suppose what i was getting at is that the higgs as a scalar has the same nonzero vacuum expectation value everywhere leaving open the possibility that vacuum value is a nonlocal variable. in that admittedly unlikely scenario it functions similarly to machs principal

I do see what you mean @R.Rankin; I’d agree with you on the technical case, but I’d still be hesitant to lend credence to Mach’s principle. A lot of crackpots/newbies try to use it to explain stuff even though it doesn’t even have a mathematical formalism; it’s best to stay away from that stuff when possible.
